# Using functions in definitions

Tags: coq

I'm modeling a program in which users can choose from different operators and functions for writing queries (i.e. formulas) for the system. For showing these operators, here I defined `add` and `mul` functions and used nat datatype, instead of my program's functions and datatypes. How should I define `formula` that enables me to use it in definition `compute_formula`. I'm a bit stuck at solving this issue. Thank you.

```
Fixpoint add n m :=
  match n with
  | 0 => m
  | S p => S (p + m)
  end
where "n + m" := (add n m) : nat_scope.


Fixpoint mul n m :=
  match n with
  | 0 => 0
  | S p => m + p * m
  end
where "n * m" := (mul n m) : nat_scope.


Definition formula : Set :=
 nat-> nat -> ?operators_add_mull  ->formula.

Definition compute_formula (f: formula) : nat :=
 match f with
  |firstnumber,secondnumber, ?operators_add_mull => 
              ?operators_add_mull  firstnumber secondnumber

  end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your syntax for defining a data type is not quite right: you need to use the `Inductive` keyword:

```
Inductive formula : Set :=
| Formula : nat -> nat -> ?operators_add_mul -> formula.
```

It remains to figure out what the arguments to the `Formula` constructor should be. The Coq function type `->` is a type like any other, and we can use it as the third argument:

```
Inductive formula : Set :=
| Formula : nat -> nat -> (nat -> nat -> nat) -> formula.
```

After defining this data type, you can write an expression like `Formula 3 5 add`, which denotes the addition of 3 and 5. To inspect the formula data type, you need to write `match` using the `Formula` constructor:

```
Definition compute_formula (f : formula) : nat :=
  match f with
  | Formula n m f => f n m
  end.
```

Comment: What if the `Inductive formula` was polymorphic with implicit arguments. How should I write the match declaration in the `Definition compute_formula`. In other words how I use polymorphic Inductive types as arguments in functions like `compute_formula`? Maybe this is totally different question.

Comment: Yeah, a new question would be better.

Comment: I wonder if there is any way to define precondition or postcondition for this function to use it in my proofs since I need to compare the result of this function for a particular datatypes.