# Using polymorphic functions in definitions

Tags: coq

Following my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218742/using-functions-in-definitions), I have several functions with different types of arguments which I defined the Inductive type `formula` on them. Is there anyway to use `Inductive formula` in `compute_formula`. I am doing this to make proving easier by decreasing the number of constructors that I have to handle in proofs. Thank you.

```
Fixpoint add (n:type1) (m:type2): type3 :=
  match n with
     (*body for add*)
  end.

Fixpoint mul (n:type1) (m:type4): type5 :=
  match n with
   (*body for mul*)
  end.

Inductive formula : Type :=
| Formula {A B}: type1-> A -> (type1->A->B) -> formula.

(* How should I write this *)
Definition compute_formula {A B} (f: formula) (extraArg:A) : B :=
 match f with
  |Formula {A B} part1 part2  part3=>  
        if (A isof type2 && B isof type3) then add part1 part2+extraArg
        if (A isof type4 && B isof type5) then mul part1 part2+extraArg     

  end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want the output type of `compute_formula` to be? The way the signature is written, the function would have to be able to compute an element of `B` no matter what `B` is. Since this is obviously impossible (what if `B` is `Empty`?), I'll show you a different approach.

The idea is to use the `formula` to get the output type.

```
Definition output_type (f: formula) :=
  match f with
  | @Formula _ B _ _ _ => B
  end.
```

Then we can define `compute_formula` as

```
Definition compute_formula (f: formula): output_type f :=
  match f with
  | @Formula _ _ t a func => func t a
  end.
```

A few other things. I'm not sure what you mean with the `extraArg` part. If you're more specific about what that means I might be able to help you. Also, there isn't (at least outside of tactics) a way to do what you want with `A isof type2`.